# Navigation Controller is unreachable error

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am am making a simple app that has 2 view controllers and I have added a navigation controller to go to another view controller with a button.
This usually works well but this time I am getting an error :

> “Navigation Controller“ is unreachable because it has no entry points, and no identifier for runtime access via -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]. [9]

How can I fix this?

You can find the entire project here:

https://github.com/vikramadit/quiz--2

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to fix this issue -

**it has no entry points** - you can mark **Is Initial View Controller** checkbox for this `NavigationController` instance. This might not be what you want.

**no identifier for runtime access via -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]** can be solved by assigning a **Storyboard ID** for this `NavigationController` instance. This is probably what you want.

The complain from Xcode is - this `NavigationController` instance can not be reached/used in any way from storyboard in code.

Comment: This fixes my error but gives me a new error:

Thread 1: "[<quiz__2.ViewController 0x7fb31790a3a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key result."

How do I deal with this?

Comment: Seems like you have an IBOutlet in storyboard called **result** that is not declared/mistyped in the **ViewController** class. You can either remove this connection from Storyboard file OR fix it by having the correct declaration in **ViewController** code.

Comment: I actually do not have nay IBOutlets in my ViewController.swift.
You can find the entire project here:
[The Project](https://github.com/vikramadit/quiz--2)

Comment: That's what I said, **Storyboard** has them, **ViewController** does NOT. In this case, you have to delete them from **Storyboard** file. You can right click on **ViewController** inside the Storyboard panel to see a corrupt **IBOutlet** entry in the list.

Comment: In the attached GitHub project you can see this corrupt entry [here](https://github.com/vikramadit/quiz--2/blob/main/quiz%20-2/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard#L109:L112).